# What are the available cheap proteins that are much less soluble than BSA

Tags: solubility, spectroscopy, proteins

Currently, as a beginner, I'm performing solubility analysis ([with UV based spectrometry](https://tools.thermofisher.com/content/sfs/manuals/Qubit_Protein_Assay_UG.pdf)) for practices.
The protein I'm using now is [BSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bovine_serum_albumin). This is widely used and cheap option.

I'm now looking for a cheap negative control protein which I can use to compare with BSA.
It has to be much less soluble than BSA.

What are the good choice of proteins for that?

Comment: Protein solubility is not a simple concept. For instance proteins are colloidal and may aggregate to form a new highly hydrated phase that may slowly form and precipitate. One way to encourage aggregation is to use a buffer at the pI of the protein, so you may be able to do this with BSA.

Comment: @BuckThorn Thanks so much. Can you advice the simple protocol to go about it?
What type of buffer, how much etc.

Comment: @BuckThorn and with your method, how can we calculate the molecular weight of the new protein we create?

Comment: One technique to determine oligomerization state and distribution is size exclusion chromatography. Whether this is the right technique depends somewhat on the size and stability of the protein aggregates.

Comment: Can you explain how you would use an insoluble protein as a negative control? Is it just a precipitate at the bottom of the cuvette? And why is that a negative control rather than just zero protein as the negative control?

Comment: @Andrew I simply want to practice making two _[standard curves](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Tabashir-Chowdhury-2/publication/235329683/figure/fig1/AS:393472059166725@1470822457973/b-BSA-calibration-curve-This-standard-curve-of-Protein-concentration-vs-absorbance-used.png)_ to show that one protein is less soluble than another.

Comment: How do you plan to make a standard curve of an insoluble protein?

Comment: @Andrew By _insoluble_  I don't mean _completely insoluble_. You still can measure the little of it that is soluble. So, in standard curve this much less soluble peptide will have lower absorbance score than those that are soluble.